# Sql Server Reporting Services and Multiple Sharepoint Farms

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I was wondering if you can have a single SSRS 2008 server be used for two different sharepoint farms?  I have a SSRS 2008 box and would like to have two different reporting instances, one for each farm.  We're in the middle of a transition from WSS --> MOSS, and I need to be able to support reporting on both.

It seems when you run the sharepoint configuration on the reporting box, it asks for the farm to connect to.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks,

-- Chad

Comment: Can you elaborate bit more.Are you trying to get Two SharePoint Farm in the Same Database Server ?. By SSRS 2008 do you mean the database server or the SQL Server Reporting Service ?.

Answer (score 1):

Reporting Services contains 2 parts, the SQL instance and the front-end.
If you want to use Reporting Services in SharePoint Integrated mode, you need to create an instance for each farm. However, both SQL instances can be in the same SQL box.
However, the reporting service front-end will need to be part of your SharePoint farm, so this part will need to be separated.

If you're planning to use the old RS webparts (iframe) or access RS webservices through code, you can do anything you want.